# Does NextAuth's AUTH_REDIRECT_PROXY_URL work for anything other than github?

Tags: javascript, next.js, oauth, next-auth

The NextAuth [docs](https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/deployment#securing-a-preview-deployment) say that AUTH_REDIRECT_PROXY_URL can be used to proxy preview deployments on Vercel. But this doesn't seem to be true, at least not wholesale.

The only place I see in the code that [uses that environment variable is for Github](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/b1c46809f5f623f4f7bb9f42fbab8d7866825997/apps/dev/nextjs/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts#L111).

I've tried using AUTH_REDIRECT_PROXY_URL with Cognito with no luck. Maybe the docs are just unclear.

Has anyone been able to get an oauth proxy working with this method? (Or otherwise).